# Heading over number position

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have a heading and number for col-md-6 and image for col-md-6.
I would like to heading slight over on number and the number should be left outside the column.

[image]

```css
.five-steps-number {
  font-size: 170px;
  color: #FFF0C2;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.five-steps-title {
  font-size: 78px;
  color: #00666A;
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-3.3.x -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">



<!-- Body -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <h3><span class="five-steps-number">1</span><span class="five-steps-title">Heading Here</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <img src="images/image-1.png" class="flt-rht">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using a framework such as Bootstrap? IF so please label your question with the correct tag (framework and version)

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I am using Bootstrap v3.3.6 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a **negative** `margin-left` to your `five-steps-title` class:

```
.five-steps-title {
  margin-left: -0.6em;
}
```

```css
.five-steps-number {
  font-size: 170px;
  color: #FFF0C2;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.five-steps-title {
  font-size: 78px;
  color: #00666A;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-left: -0.6em;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-3.3.x -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">



<!-- Body -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <h3><span class="five-steps-number">1</span><span class="five-steps-title">Heading Here</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <img src="images/image-1.png" class="flt-rht">
  </div>
</div>
```